# How to properly deploy to Netlify?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, package.json, netlify

I am having a bit of issue with properly deploying my React x Node x Express Weather Application. So far, my application is fully functional as long as I have the Server and the Frontend running at the same time, but separately. To my knowledge, I would imagine it has something to do with my package.json file scripts? (I also imagine that this is a simple fix, but I am unable to see it as I am still learning my way through Javascript).

Nonetheless, here is how my project is organized:

```
/build
/controllers
/node_modules
/public
/server
/src
.env
.gitignore
package-lock.json
package.json
README.md
```

And the server code in question runs as such, expecting a response entry from the front end, which spits out a response in the frontend fetch request:

server/index.js

```
const PORT = 8000;
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const axios = require('axios');

require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();
app.use(cors());

app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'build')))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json('hi');
});

app.get('/forecast', (req, res) => {   
    const options = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: `http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/forecast.json?`,
        params: {
            q: req.query.city,
            key : process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY,
            days: '3',
            api: 'no',
            alerts: 'no',
        }, 
    };

    axios.request(options).then((response) => {
        res.json(response.data);
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on PORT ${PORT} `))
```

My package.json looks as such:

```
{
  "name": "weather-v2",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "animate.css": "^4.1.1",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "concurrently": "^7.0.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^14.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.2",
    "fetch": "^1.1.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "node-fetch": "^3.1.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start:backend": "node server/index.js",
    "start:frontend": "react-scripts start",
    "server": "nodemon server/index.js",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "v14.16.0"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

If it makes any difference, this application was in fact created using create-react-app. Thanks for any help/suggestions and apologies once again for the convoluted-ness of the question.

Comment: What is in you `netlify.toml`? What error do you get? I am not sure netlify ever claimed to run custom backend applications at all, but that have changed since my last research.

Comment: Not sure what a netlify.toml is. This is the first time I am utilizing Netlify.